# Asynchronous syncing from S3 to local over unreliable connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to backup my S3 bucket which contain important files and want to sync the bucket to a local folder. My internet connection speed is not that high and is not stable as well. I do get frequent disconnects. I am looking for a solution that will asynchronously sync the bucket to my local folder. The file size is typically 100-200 Gigabits.

Comment: Have you tried the AWS CLI `aws s3 sync` command? If it fails, you can run the command again and it will only copy files that have not already been copied.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Will `aws s3 sync` resume downloading or start over again if run again later? Also my connection is weak and breaks at least once in 2-3 hours and I cannot complete the entire download in that duration.

Comment: It will definitely re-copy any files not previously copied. I'm not sure if it will resume a partially-downloaded file, or if it needs to restart the whole file again. Your other choice is to use a tool like CyberDuck that might be able to handle problems a bit better.